# fileReplacements in angular.cli serve configuration

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular-cli

I have a requirement to replace files in my Angular application using `fileReplacements`, but it seems that this is only available in `build` configurations, and not `serve` configurations.

Here is an extract of my `angular.json`:

```
"serve": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
  "options": {
    "browserTarget": "SupplierPortal:build"
  },
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "browserTarget": "SupplierPortal:build:production"
    },
    "fr": {
      "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
          "with": "src/environments/environment.fr.ts"
        }
      ],
      "browserTarget": "SupplierPortal:build:fr"
    }
}
```

But the compiler complains:

> Schema validation failed with the following errors:
>
> Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(fileReplacements).

Is it possible to have configurations for various serve builds?

Answer (score 11):

You almost got it. After specifying the fileReplacements in your build configurations, just need to tell to the serve configuration which build config to use.

Then you can execute `ng serve -c=fr` and the serve will apply the **fr** build configuration:

```
{
  "build": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
    "configurations": {
      "fr": {
        "fileReplacements": [{
          "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
          "with": "src/environments/environment.fr.ts"
        }]
      }
    }
  },
  "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
      "browserTarget": "SupplierPortal:build"
    },
    "configurations": {
      "production": {
        "browserTarget": "SupplierPortal:build:production"
      },
      "fr": {
        "browserTarget": "SupplierPortal:build:fr"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But that would still build with all the production options, such as `aot=true` wouldn't it? I'd have to have one build config with aot and another without, for each language.

Comment: @serlingpa you didn’t specify that in the question. But for that just add the corresponding flags to the desired build config section, for available flags check here: https://angular.io/cli/build

Comment: I cannot change the aot option for serve only as I get an error saying ```The 'buildOptimizer' option cannot be used without 'aot'``` (which is set to true in build options). And if I try to set it to false in serve options, I get ```Property buildOptimizer is not allowed```